# Legend doesn't load correctly in static RMarkdown document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard, billboard.js

I am trying to create a static html document with RMarkdown that contains a bunch of tables and graphs. A problem I am running into right now is that the legend doesn't load correctly unless it is on the landing page. I render my graphs using the `billboarder` package. I added an example:

[image]

Here's a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(billboarder)
library(data.table)
```

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Dummy tab


### Chart A

```{r}
billboarder() %>%
  bb_linechart(melt(data.table(rock, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, area := as.numeric(area)], id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = c("area", "peri")), bbaes(rn, value, variable))
```
````

Comment: tried to find a solution, but everything I tried gave me the same outcome you had, I would suggest creating an issue on the github page to see if the developers can give insight into why this is an issue.